# Load and Train Own Dataset on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I prepared the Dataset. My dataset info:

```
2000 images
200 x 200 px RGB
JPG files
4 Classes
```

How do I load and train my own Dataset? How do I perform Data Augmentation, split the Dataset, etc.?

Just like CIFAR-100 Dataset?

Comment: Can you give some more information about the dataset? How much is its size and what are the number of images?

Comment: 200x200 px images, number 2000

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading it to your google drive, and then mounting google drive on colab?

Upload your data onto your google drive.
To mount your drive on colab, run the following in your colab notebook:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive", force_remount=True)
```

Then you can use the data as you would use it in your local machine. the path to data would look like: `/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/...`

Comment: Yes ı did. But I couldn't convert it to the proper shape for the cnn.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I don't see any relation between reshaping the data and google colab. You can write the code that you want in a python file as you do for your own computer. For file read and write, use path from google drive. Then, upload that python code to your google drive. then mount drive on google colab. run your file using : `!python /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/..../code.py` (path to your file) from the google google colab notebook.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this, is first, organize the folder structure of your own Dataset exactly like this:

```
Dataset/
---- 0/
-------- img1.jpg
-------- img2.jpg
-------- ...
---- 1/
-------- img3.jpg
-------- img4.jpg
-------- ...
---- 2/
-------- img5.jpg
-------- img6.jpg
-------- ...
---- 3/
-------- img7.jpg
-------- img8.jpg
-------- ...
```

Where `'0 /'`, `'1 /'`, `'2 /'`, and `'3 /'` are the names of your 4 classes.

Compact the Dataset folder to the `.zip` format and then upload the **Dataset.zip** file to your `Google Drive`.

Now, inside your `.ipynb` file in Google Colab:

**Import some libraries:**

```
import zipfile
from google.colab import output
from google.colab import drive
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

**Mount Google Drive for fast, responsible access to files:**

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

**Unzip Dataset.zip:**

```
DATASET_PATH = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Dataset.zip'
zip_object = zipfile.ZipFile(file = DATASET_PATH,mode = 'r')
zip_object.extractall('./')
zip_object.close
```

**Select your source folder for loading the Dataset and set dimensions:**

```
DATASET = 'Dataset/'
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200
IMAGE_WIDTH = 200
```

**Implement a help-function to create Dataset from a folder:**

```
def create_dataset(DATASET_PATH):
    img_data_array = []
    class_name = []
   
    for directory in os.listdir(DATASET_PATH):
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, directory)):
            image_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, directory, file)
            image = cv.imread(image_path, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = cv.resize(image, (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
            image = np.array(image)
            image = image.astype('float32')
            image /= 255 
            img_data_array.append(image)
            class_name.append(directory)

    return img_data_array, class_name
```

**Call help-function:**

```
DATA_IMAGES, DATA_LABELS = create_dataset(DATASET)
```

**Create a dictionary for all unique values for the classes:**

```
target_dict = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(np.unique(DATA_LABELS))}
```

**Convert to their respective numeric value based on the dictionary:**

```
DATA_LABELS = [target_dict_train[DATA_LABELS[i]] for i in range(len(DATA_LABELS))]
```

**PS:** Help-function extracted from this tutorial:

- [Loading Custom Image Dataset for Deep Learning Models: Part 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-custom-image-dataset-for-deep-learning-models-part-1-d64fa7aaeca6)

**Use `train_test_split` to split the Dataset into random training-set and test-set:**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(DATA_IMAGES,
                                                    DATA_LABELS,
                                                    test_size = 0.15,
                                                    random_state = 41)
```

Where `test_size` represents the proportion of the dataset to include in the test split, and `random_state` controls the shuffling applied to the data before applying the split.

Now you have your own Dataset as input for **Deep Learning** models.

Regarding **Data Augmentation** I recommend this tutorial to read, here you can extract some insights:

- [Keras ImageDataGenerator and Data Augmentation](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/)

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!